# LRU Cache Example

Tags: java, cache

Please check the following the LRU cache implementation.

Thanks for the valuable comments

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class LRUCache {

    HashMap<Integer, Node> lruHashMap = new HashMap<>();

    private final int DEFAULT_CACHE_SIZE =5;

    int capacity = 0;

    class Node{
        int value;
        Node prev, next;
        public Node(int value, Node prev, Node next){
            this.value = value;
            this.prev = prev;
            this.next = next;
        }
        public Node(int value){
            this.value = value;
            this.prev = null;  this.next = null;
        }
    }

    Node head;
    Node tail;

    public void addData(int value){

        if(head == null) {
            head = new Node(value);
            tail = head;
            capacity++;
            lruHashMap.put(value, head);
            return;
        }

        if( lruHashMap.containsValue(value)) {
            // Item already at the linkedList and map
            // Delete node first

            Node deleteNode = lruHashMap.get(value);
            deleteNode.next.prev = deleteNode.prev;
            deleteNode.prev.next = deleteNode.next;
            deleteNode = null;
        }

        Node newNode = new Node(value,null,head);
        // Add item to head
        head.prev = newNode;
        head = head.prev;

        lruHashMap.put(value,newNode);

        ++capacity;

        checkSize(capacity);


    }

    private void checkSize(int capacity) {
        if(capacity > DEFAULT_CACHE_SIZE) {
            // remove last element
            removeLast();
        }

    }


    private void removeLast() {

        int value = tail.value;

        tail = tail.prev;
        tail.next = null;
        --capacity;

        lruHashMap.remove(value);
    }

    private void getDataOfLRUCache(){

        for(Map.Entry<Integer,Node> entry: lruHashMap.entrySet()){
            System.out.print (entry.getKey() + " - " );
            System.out.println(entry.getValue() );
        }
    }


    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return capacity == 0;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){

        LRUCache lruCache = new LRUCache();

        lruCache.addData(5);
        lruCache.addData(6);
        lruCache.addData(7);
        lruCache.addData(8);
        lruCache.addData(9);

        //   lruCache.getDataOfLRUCache();

        lruCache.addData(11);
        lruCache.addData(12);
        lruCache.getDataOfLRUCache();
    }

}
```

Comment: You could use a LinkedHashMap is specially useful for implementing an LRUCache, as it maintains a double-linked list for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have some advices for you.

- Add the `static` keyword to the `DEFAULT_CACHE_SIZE` variable ([all cap snake case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_(programming)#Java) = constant).

#### Use the size of the map instead of using the `capacity` variable

You can use `java.util.HashMap#size`. In my opinion, it will be less error-prone to do so (If you forget to update it, ect).

#### Avoid using `C-style` array declaration

In the main method, you declared a `C-style` array declaration with the `args` variable.

**before**

```java
String args[]
```

**after**

```java
String[] args
```

In my opinion, this style is less used and can cause confusion.

### Potential issues

#### Never expose directly Arrays / Collections / Maps to external classes

In this case, the `lruHashMap` map is exposed to any other instances, I highly suggest that you put the `private` keyword to hide the instance. If you don’t do so, any other classes can edit the map directly and your class will lose control over its own data.

#### Always compare objects of the same type

In the method `LRUCache#addData`, when you are checking if the `lruHashMap` contains the value, you are comparing `java.lang.Integer` with `Node`. You probably wanted to use the `java.util.HashMap#containsKey` instead.

```java
//[...]
if (lruHashMap.containsValue(value)) { // Bug, will always return false
//[...]
```

#### By setting the object null, when coming from a collection, it does not delete it from the collection.

In this case, in the `LRUCache#addData` method, you set the object null to delete it ? This will only affect the current reference of the variable `deleteNode`; not the object in the map.

```java
// Item already at the linkedList and map
// Delete node first

Node deleteNode = lruHashMap.get(value);
deleteNode.next.prev = deleteNode.prev;
deleteNode.prev.next = deleteNode.next;
deleteNode = null; // Set the `deleteNode` to null
```

### Refactored code

````java
   public class LRUCache {
      private HashMap<Integer, Node> lruHashMap = new HashMap<>();

      private static final int DEFAULT_CACHE_SIZE = 5;
      private Node head;
      private Node tail;

      class Node {
         int value;
         Node prev, next;

         public Node(int value, Node prev, Node next) {
            this.value = value;
            this.prev = prev;
            this.next = next;
         }

         public Node(int value) {
            this.value = value;
            this.prev = null;
            this.next = null;
         }
      }

      public void addData(int value) {
         if (head == null) {
            head = new Node(value);
            tail = head;
            lruHashMap.put(value, head);
            return;
         }

         if (lruHashMap.containsKey(value)) {
            // Item already at the linkedList and map
            // Delete node first

            Node deleteNode = lruHashMap.get(value);
            deleteNode.next.prev = deleteNode.prev;
            deleteNode.prev.next = deleteNode.next;
            // lruHashMap.remove(value); uncomment if you want to remote the item from the map
         }

         Node newNode = new Node(value, null, head);
         // Add item to head
         head.prev = newNode;
         head = head.prev;

         lruHashMap.put(value, newNode);

         checkSize();
      }

      private void checkSize() {
         if (lruHashMap.size() > DEFAULT_CACHE_SIZE) {
            // remove last element
            removeLast();
         }
      }


      private void removeLast() {
         int value = tail.value;

         tail = tail.prev;
         tail.next = null;

         lruHashMap.remove(value);
      }

      private void getDataOfLRUCache() {

         for (Map.Entry<Integer, Node> entry : lruHashMap.entrySet()) {
            System.out.print(entry.getKey() + " - ");
            System.out.println(entry.getValue());
         }
      }


      public boolean isEmpty() {
         return lruHashMap.isEmpty();
      }

      public static void main(String[] args) {
         LRUCache lruCache = new LRUCache();

         lruCache.addData(5);
         lruCache.addData(6);
         lruCache.addData(7);
         lruCache.addData(8);
         lruCache.addData(9);

         //   lruCache.getDataOfLRUCache();

         lruCache.addData(11);
         lruCache.addData(12);
         lruCache.getDataOfLRUCache();
      }
   }
```
````